# How to prevent double posting on Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, twitter

Our app allows users to post to Facebook and Twitter, via their API's. This means a user can select both options at the same time.

The problem here is, if they have the "Post to Facebook" setting enabled (on Twitter). Any tweet coming from our app will be double posted onto Facebook.

This can easily be prevented if Twitter's API exposed whether this setting was enabled. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Any ideas as to how this can be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to their news feed? I haven't double-checked the API documentation, but I believe you could check to see if they have other recent posts that originate from Twitter.

Comment: You are suggesting to grab the recent posts from the feed and determine whether an exact message was already posted via Twitter? Could be done, but am looking for a more elegant manner

Comment: You don't need the exact message, just to know if anything at all has been posted from Twitter.